# How can I iterate through a keyless list of jsons (string) with python?

Tags: python, json

I am using json.dumps and end up with the following json:

```
[{
"name": "Luke",
"surname": "Skywalker",
"age": 34
},
{
"name": "Han",
"surname": "Solo",
"age": 44
},
{
...
...}]
```

I would like to iterate through this list and get a person on each iteration, so on the first iteration I will get:

```
{
"name": "Luke",
"surname": "Skywalker",
"age": 34
}
```

All the examples I've seen so far are iterating using a key, for example:

```
for json in jsons['person']:
```

But Since I dont have a "person" key that holds the persons data, I have nothing to iterate through but the object structure itself or everything that is inside the - {}

When I optimistically tried:

```
for json in jsons
```

I saw that python attempted to iterate through the chars in the string that made up my json, so my first value was "["

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What you have is a list of dictionaries. Just iterate over (enumerate) the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.dumps` takes some data and turns it into a string that is the JSON representation of that data.

To iterate over the data, just iterate over it instead of calling `json.dumps` on it:

```
# Wrong!
my_data = [...]
jsons = json.dumps(my_data)
for x in jsons:
   print(x)  # prints each character in the string

# Correct:
my_data = [...]
for x in my_data:
   print(x)  # prints each item in the list.
```

If you want to go back to `my_data` from a JSON string, use `json.loads`:

```
jsons = "[{}, {}]"
my_data = json.loads(jsons)
for x in my_data:
   print(x)  # prints each item in the list.
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much, json.loads(jsons) what was I needed. I couldnt use the original data structure as it was a conversion of csv to json string:     jsons = json.dumps( [ row for row in csvReader ] )

Comment: Well, that conversion is not necessary at all: `my_data = list(csvReader)` does the same without the JSON step.

Comment: Excellent thank you! Coming from Java to Python does have its learning curve... :)